# Instagram web scraping with selenium Python problem

Tags: python, selenium, instagram, screen-scraping

I have a problem with scraping all pictures from Instagram profile, I'm scrolling the page till bottom then find all "a" tags finally always I get only last 30 links to pictures. I think that driver doesn't see full content of page.

```
#scroll
scrolldown = driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);var scrolldown=document.body.scrollHeight;return scrolldown;")
match=False
while(match==False):
    last_count = scrolldown
    time.sleep(2)
    scrolldown = driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);var scrolldown=document.body.scrollHeight;return scrolldown;")
    if last_count==scrolldown:
        match=True

#posts
posts = []
time.sleep(2)
links = driver.find_elements_by_tag_name('a')
time.sleep(2)
for link in links:
    post = link.get_attribute('href')
    if '/p/' in post:
        posts.append(post)
```

Comment: Do you see your driver scroll correctly?

Comment: Yes, scrolling works good, and always i get last 30 posts - means the oldest 30 posts

Comment: So what scrolldown variable looks? Maybe you can get links as you do below and compare len(links) vs len(old_links) to know when you dont get more, similar as you tried with last_count vs scrolldown

Comment: Thanks for the tips ;) i resolved problem - using function inside loop 'for'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you first scrolling to the page bottom and only then getting the links instead of getting the links and treating them inside the scrolling loop.
So, if you want to get all the links you should perform the

```
links = driver.find_elements_by_tag_name('a')
time.sleep(2)
for link in links:
    post = link.get_attribute('href')
    if '/p/' in post:
        posts.append(post)
```

inside the scrolling, also before the first scrolling.
Something like this:

```
def get_links():
    time.sleep(2)
    links = driver.find_elements_by_tag_name('a')
    time.sleep(2)
    for link in links:
        post = link.get_attribute('href')
        if '/p/' in post:
            posts.add(post)

posts = set()
get_links()
scrolldown = driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);var scrolldown=document.body.scrollHeight;return scrolldown;")
match=False
while(match==False):
    get_links()
    last_count = scrolldown
    time.sleep(2)
    scrolldown = driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);var scrolldown=document.body.scrollHeight;return scrolldown;")
    if last_count==scrolldown:
        match=True
```

Comment: Thank You so much, your solution works great. To avoid duplicated links i used posts = set() instead posts = []

Comment: Right! Great correction! I will update the answer.

Comment: sure, update also posts.append -> posts.add ;)